# Why I can't perform a regex on this "string" returned by this subprocess module method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am pretty new in Python and I am finding some problem with **regex**

Into a program on which I am working I have these lines of code:

```
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
print(ifconfig_result)

mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
print(mac_address_search_result.group(0))
```

The first line perform an **ifconfig** command on a Linux system (using the subprocess module). Then I print this output, I am obtaining this output:

```
b'eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500\n        inet 192.168.223.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.223.255\n        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feb9:fdf6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>\n        ether 00:0c:29:b9:fd:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)\n        RX packets 69731  bytes 94090876 (89.7 MiB)\n        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0\n        TX packets 31405  bytes 3383293 (3.2 MiB)\n        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0\n\n'
```

Then I am trying to use a regex to extract only the MAC address containing in this returned "string" (I think that this is not a propper string).

The problem is that on this line performing the regex:

```
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
```

I obtain the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mac_changer.py", line 46, in <module>
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

So it seems to me that the ifconfig_result objet returned by the **check_output()** method of the **subprocess** object is not a string but something like binary (what exactly is)

Why have I this behavior? (I am following a tutorial where it is illustrated in this way).

How can I obtain a propper string so I can use my regex?

Comment: `check_output` supports a `text` option that you can set if you know the process output will all be ASCII, which will cause the result to be returned as a `str` instead of a `bytes`.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the `decode` function, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/534674)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that what you have is not a `str` but a `bytes`.

Either you convert it to a `str`

```
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result.decode("utf8"))
```

Or you use a `bytes` matcher

```
mac_address_search_result = re.search(rb"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes."

[What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)